# Factorial function returning squared number and not factorial

Tags: vba, factorial

Where is my code wrong? It is returning the square of any number:

```
Sub factorial()
Dim x As Long, i As Integer, fact As Long
   x = InputBox("enter the integer")
   For i = 1 To x
      fact = i * x
      Next i
   MsgBox fact
End Sub
```

Comment: https://riptutorial.com/vba/example/11107/factorials

Comment: @braX - the OP code is faster than the link you have provided. `O(n)`  is the best you may ask for a factorial calculation.

Comment: I just picked a random example of the hundreds of results that came up using google.

Comment: @braX - I know. But as factorial is usually "the thing" people give as an example, when introducing recursion, 95% of the results with google are extremely slow. The other 4.5% percent use memoization and are a bit faster and the tiny 0.5% that actually do the job quickly are a simple loop as the one from the OP.

Comment: besides, dosent excel have a worksheet function for that anyway?

Comment: @braX - `worksheetfunction.fact(n)` is the one that returns that exactly. And I really hope it is not implemented with recursion :D

Comment: Note that in VBA `Integer` is 16bit and `Long` is 32bit. So  you need `LongLong` types for 64bit integers that wont overflow (easily).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Practicing Loops and `If` Statements!?

```vb
Option Explicit

' If you are practicing (loops) then:
Sub factorial()
    Dim x As Long, i As Long, fct As Double
    x = InputBox("enter the integer")
    If x >= 0 And x <= 170 Then
        fct = 1
        If x > 1 Then
            For i = 2 To x
                fct = fct * i
            Next i
        End If
        MsgBox fct
    Else
        MsgBox "Next time enter a number between 0 and 170."
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub

' ...if not, just use Fact
Sub factorialExcel()
    Dim x As Long
    x = InputBox("enter the integer")
    If x >= 0 And x <= 170 Then
        MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.Fact(x)
    Else
        MsgBox "Next time enter a number between 0 and 170."
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: ```
Sub factorial()
    Dim x As Long, i As Long, fact As Long
    x = InputBox("enter the integer")
    If x < 0 Then
        MsgBox "enter a positive number."
        ElseIf x > 1 Then
        For i = 2 To x
            fact = fact * i
        Next i
    End If
    MsgBox fact
End Sub
```
i have used this. but the output is coming 0  @VBasic2008

Comment: You have to use `fact = 1` before, because when you do `Dim Fact As Long`, then `Fact` is equal to `0`. Also if you use rather `Dim Fact As Double` you can get results for up to `170`. With long you get only results up to `12`. Look at my first example. Vityata's solution also has `fact = 1` for the same reason.

Comment: I think `Double` can represent integers up to `2^53-1`, vs a `LongLong` type can go up to `2^63-1`, so a much larger range of possible outputs.

Answer (score 1):

One mistake is that `fact` needs to be initialized with `fact=1` before it is used in the loop. Then inside the loop the result is should be multiplied by the iteration number, as in `fact = fact * i`. Lastly to make sure you get the highest possible range use the `LongLong` type (available in VB7 and above) which is a 64-bit integer. Oh, and don't forget to convert the text returned by `InputBox` to a number type.

```
Sub factorial()
Dim x As Long, i As Long, fact As LongLong
   x = CLng(InputBox("enter the integer"))
   fact = 1
   For i = 1 To x
      fact = fact * i
   Next i
   MsgBox fact
End Sub
```

PS. *Never* use `Integer` in VBA, but rather opt for the native 32-bit integer `Long`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code the value of `fact` is recalculated on any iteration and it is not kept. So at the end, just the last value is shown, which is `x*i` where `i=x`, e.g. a square of the input. Something like this, using 90% of your code works:

```
Sub Factorial()

    Dim x As Long, i As Long, fact As Long
    x = 5
    fact = 1
    For i = 1 To x
        fact = fact * i
    Next i
    
    Debug.Print fact
    
End Sub
```